# Stored procedure to enter Results into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I am attempting to create a stored procedure take the data from a C# program and then input the data into a table called `dbo.Results` gathering the UserID from the `dbo.People` table.

```
create Procedure InsertResults
    @ForName nvarchar(50),
    @Surname nvarchar(50)
    @RaceID int,
    @Place int,
    @Fleet nchar(10)
AS
Begin

Insert Into [dbo].[Results] values
    (IDENT_CURRENT(dbo.Results),@RaceID,(Select UserID From dbo.People Where (ForName = @ForName and Surname = @Surname)),@Place,@Fleet)
End
```

Where when I execute the SQL Query to create the Procedure it returns

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure InsertResults, Line 11 [Batch Start Line 0]
> The multi-part identifier "dbo.Results" could not be bound.

Comment: Check the documentation for "insert" - identities are created automatically, you don't do anything as part of the insert. Also best practice is to list the columns being inserted into.

Comment: you need to (SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.Results'))

Comment: @DougCoats Never use `IDENT_CURRENT` for looking up the ID of a row you just inserted. Instead use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

Comment: Your **application** should be passing the UserID value, not the name. It is a bad habit to retrieve lookup information for use by your application and not keep track of the primary key values for any items selected from those lookups. This will avoid issues when you have multiple rows with similar (or same) display values.

Comment: @charlieface I was just answering the question as it was presented (him trying to figure out how to make what was presented work) not questioning his logic. It isnt clear if he wanted to get "the most recent values" or get the "newly inserted values." Seeing how the question presented it isnt clear what exactly he wants, though now that it has an accepted answer (it didnt when i commented) it is more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `IDENT_CURRENT()` takes a string, but [you don't want to do that anyway](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/01/t-sql-queries/ident-current)
- you leave out the `IDENTITY` column rather than trying to look it up

  - this means you can't be lazy; you need to [name your columns](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)
- if you are trying to `INSERT ... SELECT` you don't use `VALUES`:

  ```
  INSERT dbo.Results(all,cols,except,identity)
    SELECT @RaceID,UserID,@Place,@Fleet
      FROM dbo.People 
      WHERE ForName = @ForName 
        AND Surname = @Surname;
  ```

*(Also, makes me wonder what you expect to happen when you have two different people named `John Smith`.)*